# How to get the max value for different instances

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data. I wanted to find the max value for these data

Raw Data

```
Date        Name    Hour    Data
20210615    Jack    0   92.28
20210615    Jack    1   92.02
20210615    Jack    2   89.51
20210615    Jack    3   89.13
20210615    Jack    4   89.42
20210615    Jack    5   90.55
20210615    Jack    6   92.25
20210615    Jack    7   93.97
20210615    Jack    8   89.59
20210615    Jack    9   90.25
20210615    John    1   91.55
20210615    John    2   90.71
20210615    John    3   90.71
20210615    John    4   92.56
20210615    John    5   91.09
20210615    John    6   91.36
20210615    John    7   92.1
20210615    John    8   92.4
20210615    John    9   93.02
```

My requirement is to get the output as which is the max value

```
Date    Name    Hour    Data
20210615    Jack    7   93.97
20210615    John    9   93.02
```

I was using the following code, but it gives me only one value

```
df = df[df.data == df.data.max()]
```

Pl help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `drop_duplicates()`+`sort_values()`:

```
out=df.sort_values('Data',ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['Date','Name'])
```

output of `out`:

```
    Date        Name    Hour    Data
7   20210615    Jack    7       93.97
18  20210615    John    9       93.02
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a groupby to get the index of the max and filter the original dataframe with the index:

```
# the .array is unnecessary and can be ignored
df.loc[df.groupby(['Date', 'Name']).Data.idxmax().array]
 
        Date  Name  Hour   Data
7   20210615  Jack     7  93.97
18  20210615  John     9  93.02
```